# Copy one table data into another db by using INTO Select

Tags: sql-server

I am getting this error :

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 39
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'in'

My code:

```
SELECT * 
INTO EmployeesBackup IN 'DB2.mbd' 
FROM Employee
```

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is off, and perhaps you intended to do an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO DB2.EmployeesBackup
SELECT *
FROM DB1.Employee;
```

This would work assuming that both databases are on the same server, and that your backup table `EmployeesBackup` has the same definition as the `Employee` table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO [DBName].dbo.EmployeesBackup
SELECT * FROM [DBName].dbo.Employee
```

Please note that, Either both `database` should be available on the same SQL Server OR if one of them is available on the different server then it should be `Linked`